# Django-template. How to create list of values for specific key for each element in QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am sending all objects to html through context:

**views.py**

```
def books(request):

    all_books = Book.objects.all()
    context = {'books': all_books}

    return render(request, 'books/books.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.IntegerField()
    offset_pages = models.IntegerField()
    read_pages = models.IntegerField()
    total_pages = models.IntegerField()
    book_path = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category} | {self.title} | {self.author}'
```

Is this possible to get a list of all values for specific key in django template?

I would like to have a list of all read_pages values for each element in QuerySet.

I can do this through a context as well I believe, but it seems like there has to be a better way.

I need a list because I want to send it do chart.js later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in Javascript, the best thing is to transform the queryset to JSON in the views:

```
from django.core import serializers

def books(request):

    all_books = Book.objects.all()
    serialized_books = serializers.serialize('json', [ all_books, ])
    context = {'books': all_books, 'books_json': serialized_books}

    return render(request, 'books/books.html', context)
```

Then you can pass `serialized_books` to Javascript in the Django template as follows:

```
<script>
    var books_serialized='{{ books_json | safe }}';
</script>
```

You can then get the object in your Javascript file and get any attribute:

```
let books = JSON.parse(books_serialized)
Object.keys(books[0]).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key==="fields"){
        console.log(books[key]["read_pages"]);
    }   
});
```

Comment: I like your solution, but it doesn't work yet. I got error: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'. Should I modify my models as well then to add class Meta?

Comment: I usually add the `Meta` to any model, but which line of code is causing this error?